# Data from PostgreSQL to JSON via Ruby

Tags: angularjs, ruby, json, http

I want to display data from my database with Angular using Ruby as my backend language.

I have rb file "income-json.rb" :

```
require 'pg'
require 'json'

begin
  conn = PG.connect :dbname=>'rails_agi_development'
  res = conn.exec("select * from incomes") #res represent all the data in this table

  data_array = []
  res.each_with_index {|val,index| #val is the actual data and index is the index number
    data_array << val
  }

  puts data_array.to_json
  conn.close
end
```

Above will generate a JSON into the console when I run `ruby income-json.rb`.

Now I want to use this data in my Angular app using $http service:

```
var incomeApp = angular.module('incomeApp',[]);

incomeApp.controller('indexCtrl',['$scope','$http',"$templateCache", function($scope,$http,$templateCache){
  $scope.method="GET";
  $scope.url="/income-json.rb"
  $scope.fetch = function(){
    $scope.code = null;
    $scope.response = null;
    $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: $templateCache}).then(function(res){
      $scope.status=res.response;
      $scope.data=res.data;
    }, function(res){
      $scope.data=res.data || "Request Failed";
      $scope.status=res.status;
    });
  };

}]);
```

Then let say I want to show the data in my view:

```
<div ng-app="incomeApp" ng-controller="indexCtrl">
  <h1>Income Index</h1>
  {{data}}
</div>
```

Doesn't seem it is working with no data came back, what should I do?

Comment: You really want to be using something like [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org) for your back-end, or something more light-weight like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) at the very least. CGI mode execution of Ruby is really, really slow in comparison.

Comment: ...And CGI is nowhere near as easy to work with compared to Rails or Sinatra. Also, instead of using Pg, use an ORM like Sequel or Active Record. Sinatra and Sequel is a very good combination, as is Active Record which is part of Rails, and Rails. Your future self will thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "Doesn't seem it is working as planned..." mean? Please read "[mcve]".